# grepl precedence logical operators R

Tags: r, subset, operator-precedence, grepl

I am a beginner and try to subset rows of a data frame by using grepl and a combination of logical operators. Somehow, I can't make it work. My aim is to capture all rows that in a certain column contain different combinations of values.

Given this data frame,

```
Col1 <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
Col2 <- c("a,b,c", "a,b,e", "a,y,z", "x,y,z")

df <- data.frame(Col1, Col2)
```

I want to capture all rows in which `a and b` appear together `or` `a and z` appear together.

My code looks like this:

```
df.sub<-subset(df, grepl("a&b|a&z", df$Col2))
```

and

```
df.sub<-subset(df, grepl("a & (b|c)", df$Col2))
```

Neither works.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `grepl("a.*[bz]", df$Col2)` ?

Comment: You can search [regular expression wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for more details.

Comment: Well, that is a solution to my problem. Thank you.